# what to expect at the client side when returning false from BeforeSaveEntity

Tags: breeze

I'm looking for documentation about what to expect at the client side when returning false from BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo) but i found nothing so I decided to experiment myself.

I made a test on the Doccode project:

```
test("create customer returning false from contextprovider", 1, function () {

    var em = newEm();
    var category = em.createEntity('Category', { CategoryName: 'Julian Category' });

    stop();

    em.saveChanges().then(function (saveResult) {
        //ok(category.entityAspect.entityState.isAdded(), "Added state because contextprovider return false");
        ok(em.hasChanges() === false,"No changes pending");
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        debugger;
    })
    .fin(function () {
        start();
    });
});
```

And i found that the two assertions were true, so i think that it may be a bug.

To make the test i created a custom provider:

```
public class CustomEFContextProvider : EFContextProvider<NorthwindContext>
{
    public CustomEFContextProvider() : base()
    {

    }

    protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
    {
        if(entityInfo.Entity.GetType() == typeof( Category)){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and changed the NorthwindController to use it:

```
readonly CustomEFContextProvider _contextProvider =
    new CustomEFContextProvider();
```

I'm returning false when a Category is saved, so the category doesn't get inserted on the database and it's not returned in the saveResult.entities array. The keyMappings is also empty. All of this is what i expected.
What i didn't expect is that the entitymanager.hasChanges function returns false because the category entity is marked as added, what in my opinion leaves the manager inconsistent.

It's a bug? I'm doing something wrong? Were my expectations wrong?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as of v 1.2.5 ( just released), this should be fixed.  Please post back to confirm if possible, and thx for the bug report. :)

Comment: The bug is solved, but one question: Suppose I'm saving a complex graph, how can I know which entities were not saved? Do I need to traverse the entire graph?
And please, can you answer to my question in the last comment of the other answer? Thx.

Comment: You can call EntityManager.getEntities(null, [EntityState.Added, EntityState.Modified, EntityState.Deleted]) at any time to see all of the "unsaved" entities in an EntityManager. ... not sure I understand the other question. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not so good :) I don't need nothing more, I see that my assumptions were right and I'm doing this: 
I'm modifying the KeyMapping on SaveChangesCore to include the new ID for the entity that I'm saving manually. Then at the client side, breeze detects that there is a mapping from the old ID to the new ID and updates the entity ID and then I call entity.acceptChanges.

Comment: No problem. We appreciate your finding the bugs. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hm... it's an interesting question.

The reason that EntityManager.hasChanges returns true is that you haven't saved the "added" Category object, and therefore breeze doesn't call **EntityAspect.acceptChanges** on it because it is still in fact in an "added" **but not savable state**.

I think this is actually the right behavior, because if we were to call acceptChanges automatically on this entity, you would never know on the client that it had not been saved. You can of course call acceptChanges directly within the promise callback.

Does this make sense?

Comment: just to clarify, the hasChanges function returns false, not true.

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for the correction.
Just for clarify, I'm returning false because I need to save the entity in a different way, so in addition to return false, I understand that I need to modify the KeyMapping on SaveChangesCore to include the new ID from the entity. Then at the client side, breeze will see that there is a map from oldID to newID and will update the entity ID and all that i must do is to call acceptChanges at the entity.
I'm right?